# High score table php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple project, I want to fetch the high score which is like high score on the top and lowest score in the bottom as the other games have score table.

I have done

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [Colname] DESC;
```

It made the high scorer on the top of the table and sort the table as descending order but php still fetching data ASCENEDING order . Which is not the high scorer.

## Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action

1   id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change   Drop

2   addDate timestamp           No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop

3   name    varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL        Change

4   score   int(11)         Yes NULL        Change Change   Drop Drop

5   image   varchar(64) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL

Comment: `desc` instead of `DECS`. But I guess thats a typo

Comment: replace `DECS` with `DESC`

Comment: Show the table schema and some sample data

Comment: how can I show here?

Comment: thanks All ITS RESOLVED NOW

Answer (score 1):

Data type on that column must be wrong. Probably you are using one of text data types, and for example 11 is below 100 because text sorting works alphabetically character after character. First digits are the same, second digit in 100 is 0 (before 1)

Comment: please check above the datatypes